# Parse the xml response Strange

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xml, quickblox

I am trying to send request to an api by what i get response is strange one.

I am attaching the response as image.

[image]

Here is the Real XML Response in text

```
<data type="array" class_name="Location" skip="0" limit="0">
  <Location>
    <_id>558a8325535c1246bb00d5c5</_id>
    <_parent_id>test-api</_parent_id>
    <created-at type="integer">1435140901</created-at>
    <lat type="float">11.0270643</lat>
    <location>Avarampalayam, Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu, India</location>
    <long type="float">76.9830277</long>
    <updated-at type="integer">1435140901</updated-at>
    <user-id type="integer">3566216</user-id>
  </Location>
  <Location>
    <_id>558a83dd535c12843900dbbe</_id>
    <_parent_id>test-api</_parent_id>
    <created-at type="integer">1435141085</created-at>
    <lat type="float">11.0310806</lat>
    <location>Mettupalayam Bus Stand, Mettupalayam Road, Tatabad, Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu, India</location>
    <long type="float">76.9525282</long>
    <updated-at type="integer">1435141085</updated-at>
    <user-id type="integer">3566216</user-id>
  </Location>
</data>
```

Which comes under `#document`

How can i fetch the values in the above given response?

Here is the way i use to request

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.quickblox.com/data/Location',
    data: { token:'662d3330f192b4af77d5eef8de58f7e8c01a12a7' },
    method: 'get',
    success: function(msg) {
        var value = msg;
        console.log(msg);
    }
})
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but It's not JSON, it's XML. And as far as I know the `#document` is just an addition of the browser. Take a look how the data really look in your `network` tab.

Comment: Funny looking JSON you've got there. To get the values you simply need to traverse the *XML* that's returned. If you add your code which is making the request to the question, we can show you how to do this.

Comment: @OfirBaruch Extremely sorry, its xml, got it,, updated

Comment: As mentioned earlier, the `#document` isn't really in the response, it's just an addition of the browser. In order to work with XML, consider reading about `parseXML` https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/. **Ignore** it and take a look @RoryMcCrossan's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery's standard DOM traversal functions on the returned XML to retrieve the values you require. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.quickblox.com/data/Location',
    data: {
        token:'662d3330f192b4af77d5eef8de58f7e8c01a12a7'
    },
    method: 'get',
    dataType: 'xml', // note this is optional as jQuery should detect and parse it for you automatically
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).filter('data').find('Location').each(function() {
            var id = $(this).find('_id').text();
            var parentId = $(this).find('_parent_id').text();
            var createdAt = new Date($(this).find('created-at').text());
            var lat = parseFloat($(this).find('lat').text());
            // retrieve the other properties...

            // work with them here...
        });            
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you debugged at all? Check the console for errors in your code, or with the request?

Answer (score 1):

The right way is to use JSON instead of XML on web

So first of all replace urls with

```
url: 'https://api.quickblox.com/data/Location.json'
```

then you can simply access any key you need

Also there is a Web SDK http://quickblox.com/developers/Javascript
so you can use it to make requests

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me in this please ... It was posted for my friend .. thanks : ) http://stackoverflow.com/q/31218982/4538704